# How to auto increment Id with VARCHAR or NVARCHAR in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

I used to do that using a compound column in my SQL code before.

```
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[PreFix] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[EmployeeNo]  AS ([PreFix]+ RIGHT('0000000' + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(7)), 7)) PERSISTED,
```

Comment: I guess there is no way to reliably do it in the application layer because you can't guarantee your new ID hasn't already been taken in someone elses application

Comment: Have you considered using GUID? Or if in your case, you cannot use GUID I can write a simple solution.

Comment: In my case, I don't need GUID. I want to prefix the ID with some characters like EM or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are mainly different workarounds, the simplest would be modifying the `OnModelCreating` method to use one of the fluent API functions `HasComputedColumnSql` on the computed column.

**Code First Approach**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
    .Property(e => e.EmployeeNo)
    .HasComputedColumnSql("[PreFix]+ RIGHT('0000000' + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(7)), 7)");
}
```

**Database First Approach**

For a database first approach you could still have the computation logic defined while creating the table and use the following modification in the context side of the entity framework core.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
            .Property(p => p.EmployeeNo)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    }
```